Why can't I just quit after running a docker container in terminal/bash?
PS C:\Users\abhis\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\pay\backend> docker run -p 3000:3000 server

backend@1.0.0 start
nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 3.1.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
[nodemon] watching path(s): .
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting node index.js
MONGODB Database connected
Connected to http://localhost:3000
T was expecting to get out of the docker container like we use ctrl + c to quit the local server in node or react.But that cmd not working here i tried pressing q , ctrl + c . I know i can add -d to my docker run but still if there would be some cmd that solve my this problem

If you've started your container with the wrong options, usually the right approach is to docker stop the container (if C-c hasn't already stopped it), docker rm it, and docker run it again with the corrected options.

To detach from an attached container, you press ctrl+p ctrl+q.
